# Refreshing page from browser (Backbone.js and ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a single page application with several controllers and actions in each controller all of which return a json result if the page is accessed from a mobile device.

Backbone than loads the correct view according the specified url and parses the json. Using underscore.js than I am compiling the template and finally showing it inside a div.

This works fines until I refresh the browser. On refresh the action from the REST application is sending the JSON back to the browser but obviously without loading any templates.

Is there a workaround to this problem for example I have tried Redirecting to the index page with a hash behind it ("Index#MyPage").

In this case backbone loads the Index page than recognizes that it needs to go the "MyPage" route and load it's Json (and it does), but the template is still not being loaded.

Comment: Are you using Backbone router (http://backbonejs.org/#Router)? If so, you could deal with the  model `fetch`ing and view creation/rendering there.

Comment: Yes i am using Backbone router, and In the Initialize method I am adding the necessary routes to render the views. The problem is that after refreshing the browser I need to redirect somewhere so that backbone knows it needs to re-initialize

Comment: If you have your routes to render your views, one thing you could do would be to ```fetch``` the model and only render the view on the ```success``` callback (or ```done``` if you're using promises).

Comment: "If you're using promises" are you referring to something similar to this [link](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/07/rewriting-my-guaranteed-callbacks-code-with-jquery-deferred/)

Comment: Yes, kind of. This [link](http://quickleft.com/blog/leveraging-deferreds-in-backbonejs) illustrates what I was suggesting.